# How to select permisisons list for user by query?

Tags: postgresql

I have set permissions for PUBLIC role:

```
grant update on table to PUBLIC;
grant select on table to user1;
```

I.e.I did not set update permission for user1.

How to select the list of actual permissions for user1 by query?

Comment: [`table_privileges`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-table-privileges.html) for example...

Comment: When I select from this table I receive only permissions set for user1. But user1 has all what PUBLIC has too and I do nto see them. I mean how to select actual permissions set by one query